# Heroku deploy succeeds but shows application error

Tags: node.js, heroku

Right now, I'm using Heroku to deploy my app from GitHub. Here's deploy output log:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  16.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 16.x...
       Downloading and installing node 16.3.0...
       Using default npm version: 7.15.1
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       
       added 149 packages, and audited 150 packages in 9s
       
       10 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
-----> Build
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       
       up to date, audited 150 packages in 866ms
       
       10 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 48M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
       https://dino-pack.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

However, when I go to `dino-pack.herokuapp.com`, it shows me this:
[image]

What is the problem, and how can I fix it? I've tried deleting and re-making the application, but it still shows this.

Answer (score 0):

As near as I can tell from your logs there appears to be a path resolution issue. Some modules don't handle relative paths very well.

If you have an import somewhere that uses a relative path I would try changing that to either a relative format that works or first try an absolute path and see what shows up in the logs then.

This is just a guess since you don't want to share your code.

Comment: I'm doing this from GitHub, not from the command line.

Comment: You should still be able to find the logs. If you log into heroku the logs are available from within your app. There is a drop down near the upper right corner with an option that says view logs. This is different from the build logs that you already shared. It will be noticeably so, as well. But getting the command line tool is much easier and highly recommended.

Comment: The logs I found are here: https://pastebin.com/UgWj3hgE.

Comment: I double checked, there was a file named `app.js` in the parent directory.

Comment: where did you install the "dino-pack" package from? it doesn't appear to be in the npm registry.

Comment: a Procfile primarily tells heroku how you want your app to be started. but when you have a package.json file present it knows that you want to use node. and it runs what ever you have as the value for your start command within the scripts object.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your setup was done correctly, Procfile and the package.json. Follow a setup guide to double check. I'm sure it's a silly error but we need more info to find out what it is.

Comment: I didn't do anything for a Procfile. What is it?

Comment: Try following this guide. Clone the getting started project and check out the procfile.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#prepare-the-app

In simple terms,  you use the Procfile to tell Heroku how to run various pieces of your app